# Server side MVC framework supporting sub-projects

Tags: model-view-controller

I am wondering if there is a server side MVC framework, in any language which supports creating Sub-projects.

For example something like this:

```
-Root project
|-- Project A
|-- Project B
|-- Project C
|-Root project files (such as route list, config files and etc...)
```

Each Sub-project and the Root project have the same structure.
Note that this is just an example, any other structure is fine, as long as it is MVC and supports sub-projects.

Comment: Usually, if they don't want to seem dumb, people start by naming the language(s) in which the framework would be  ..

Comment: @tereško, If you look at the question, I have state "any language". I am trying to learn how such a framework accomplishes that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET MVC. The AREA feature is pretty much what you are describing.

http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html
https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/